# Flow data is not showing in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-mvvm, kotlin-stateflow

I'm trying to get data from server and cache into database and return new fetched list to user. I'm getting response form server and saving it to the local database but when im trying to observer it from composable function it showing list is empty.

When i try to debug and collect flow data in myViewModel class it showing but it not showing is composable function.

dao

```
@Dao
interface CategoryDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(categories: List<Category>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY name")
    fun read(): Flow<List<Category>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM categories")
    suspend fun clearAll()
}
```

repository class:

```
    suspend fun getCategories(): Flow<List<Category>> {
        val categories = RetrofitModule.getCategories().categories
        dao.insert(categories)
        return dao.read()
    }
```

myViewModel

```
    fun categoriesList(): Flow<List<Category>> {
        var list: Flow<List<Category>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
        viewModelScope.launch {
            list = repository.getCategories().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        }
        return list
    }
```

Observing from:

```
@Composable
fun StoreScreen(navController: NavController, viewModel: CategoryViewModel) {
    val list = viewModel.categoriesList().collectAsState(emptyList())
    Log.d("appDebug", list.value.toString()) // Showing always emptyList []
}
```

current response :

```
2021-05-15 16:08:56.017 5125-5125/com.demo.app D/appDebug: []
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are never updating the `value` of `MutableStateFlow` which has been collected as state in the `Composable` function.

Also you are assigning a `Flow` type object to a `MutableStateFlow` variable.

We can just update the value of the `collected` flow in the compose using:-

```
mutableFlow.value = newValue
```

We need to change the type of list to `MutableStateFlow<List<Category>>` instead of `Flow<List<Category>>`

Try this:-

```
 var list: MutableStateFlow<List<Category>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList()) // changed the type of list to mutableStateFlow
 viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.getCategories().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).collect { it ->
         list.value = it
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But list.value isn't showing

Comment: please check my full answer , it will show when we initialize `list` using `var list: MutableStateFlow<List<Category>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())` @Jonas